# Setting Timezone for IntelliJ Cassandra Database Viewer

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cassandra, timezone

I'm writing some Java code interacting with Cassandra. I was wondering if there is any way to adjust the timezone for displaying (not for storing) columns of `TIMESTAMP` types.

[image: A column of timestamp type]

As far as I understand, Cassandra's `TIMESTAMP` type is essentially a number of milliseconds since the epoch[[2](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html)], hence there is no notion of *timezone* for the type and the viewer shows the time as in UTC.

Here's what I have tried:

According to [JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html), there's a JVM option `user.timezone` to make this kind of adjustment. So I've set the JVM option of the Cassandra driver as `-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul`, but it appears to have no effect whatsoever. Also tried `-Duser.timezone=UTC+09:00` and it didn't work either.

Is there any way to make the viewer to show the times in a different timezone?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue? I'm also facing this issue from long time and it does not work after adding VM Options.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn’t recognize `UTC+09:00` as a time zone ID.

Use for example `-Duser.timezone=Asia/Pyongyang` or an even better suited ID in the *region/city* format, or `-Duser.timezone=Etc/GMT-9` if you insist on giving an offset rather than a time zone. In the latter case note the inverted sign, `-9` for `+09:00`.

Recognized time zone IDs are in [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've also tried `-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul` and that didn't work either.

Comment: In that case I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I appreciate your comment though.